# Function with local extreme value at a point but not monotone in any of its neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

In a question a function is given as-

$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^4(2+sin(\frac{1}{x})) & \text{if x$\neq$ 0} \\[2ex] 0 & \text{if x=0}\end{cases}$

In this function, $f'(0)$ comes out to be 0 (and f has minima at 0) and in every neighborhood of 0, $f'(x)$ has both positive and negative values which implies that in every neighborhood of 0, $f(x)$ is not monotonic.
It is easy to prove.

If $f$ has an extreme value at zero then there should $\exists$ a neighborhood in the left such that $f$ is monotonic decreasing to $f(0)$ and a neighborhood at right such that $f$ increases monotonic to right from $f(0)$ or vice versa if the function is continuous.

But this example suggest that $\not\exists$ any neighbourhood of 0 in which function becomes monotone.

Calculations suggest that $f$ has minima at 0 and $f'(x)$ changes its sign in every neighborhood of $0$. But why  $f$ has a minimum at 0? It seems somewhat surprising to me.

Comment: The claim in your third paragraph ("If $f$ has an extreme value at zero...") is simply wrong. As you yourself can see!

Comment: Suppose f has a local minima at 0 then there is a neighborhood of 0 in which elements of D(f) at left of 0 should decrease to f(0) and right of 0 increase from f(0) monotonically.

Comment: No, the example shows that this statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a picture will help.  Your function does indeed have a minimum at $0$, in fact it is always between $x^4$ and $3 x^4$, but the graph is so wiggly as $x \to 0$ that there are
no intervals $(0,\epsilon)$ or $(-\epsilon, 0)$ on which it is monotonic.

[image]

Comment: Ok, now I understand.

Comment: (+1) The neat thing about a picture such as this is that we can now easily see that it's possible without worrying about finding some type of explicit formula for the function (and verifying that it works), and we can also easily see that other possibilities exist, such as the situation when a nowhere differentiable (for $x \neq 0)$ continuous function is inserted between the graphs of $x^4$ and $3x^4.$

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ has a minimum at $0$ since:

- $f(0)=0$;
- if $x\ne0$, $f(x)>0$.

Comment: Ok, so this happens only because f(x)>0 $\forall x\neq 0$, though it is monotonic increasing or decreasing in every nbd. of 0.If the function decreases to f(0)=0 in every neighbourhood of 0 then we can't regard f(0) as local minimum, doesn't it?

Comment: But your function is *not* monotonic on any interval centered at $0$.