# $f$ positive, continuous and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) =0$. Then $f$ is decreasing after some point.

Tags: calculus, analysis

I need to prove this result for my thesis. It would be nice if someone could comment on my solution.
If $f$ is positive continuous and  $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) =0$ then it is decreasing.
The intuition is that after some $x_1,\ f(x)$ will be decreasing for any $x>x_1$ since $f$ is positive and its limit is $0$. Here is what I did:

Since $f$ is positive we can write the defintion of the limit as follows:
$$ \forall\ \epsilon\ \exists\ \xi\ : f(x) < \epsilon\ \forall\ x > \xi.$$

Therefore for any $x_1,\ x_2,\ x_2 > x_1 > \xi\ $ we can set $\epsilon = f(x_1)$ and therefore:
$$x_2 > x_1 \Rightarrow f(x_2) < f(x_1). $$
So f is decreasing for any $x > \xi.$

Is this correct? Am I missing something?
**EDIT**
Indeed I cannot generalise this.
The function I am working on is this one:
$$f(\alpha) = \frac{1}{1+ \sum_{h=1}^{m}(1+\alpha)^{-h}+ \sum_{h=1}^{n}(1+\alpha)^h},\ \alpha >0. $$
$m,n \in \mathbb N$.
I know it is decreasing but I just cannot show it.

Comment: No, it is not correct. Draw a picture ... it is simpler to start with a picture. What you are missing is that $x_2$ may have to be "large" and "decreasing" requires only $x_2 > x_1$.

Comment: It's not true, just look at $f(x)=\sin^2(x)/x$

Comment: Account for the derivative of f instead, since it must be decreasing, then $f(a) \leq f(b)$, which you can prove by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: You can likely take $f(x) = \frac1{1+|x|^2}( W(x) +2 |\inf W|)$ for a horrible bounded continuous function $W$ so that it is nowhere decreasing

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3690961 for a counterexample.

Comment: I have pointed out the error in your argument.

Comment: You are right, I was too naive. Thanks for your answers I have edited the post to make it more specific.

Comment: @AndreasGeorgiou This case is an example for an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false. Take the piecewise linear function that takes the following values:

$$0\mapsto 1\\
1\mapsto \frac13\\
2\mapsto \frac12\\
3\mapsto \frac14\\
4\mapsto \frac13\\
\vdots$$ as a counterexample.

---

It is also possible to construct a smooth counterexample, for example
$$f: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R\\
f(x)=e^{-x}(1.1 + \sin x)$$

You can see that the funciton's derivative is $e^{-x}(\cos x -\sin x - 1.1) = e^{-x} \left(\sqrt{2} \sin\left(\frac \pi 4 - x\right) - 1.1\right)$ which takes both negative and positive values on any interval of length $2\pi$.

Comment: Maybe $e^{-x}$ instead of $e^x$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Yes, of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument fails because $\xi$ depends on $\epsilon$. So $x_1 >\xi$ already puts some restriction on $x_1$ in terms of $\epsilon$ and you cannot set $\epsilon =f(x_1)$.

This is false and there are simple counter-examples. Take $f(x)=\frac {1+sin^{2} x} {x^{2}}$.  To see that this function does not decrease after any stage look at the values at $n\pi$ and $(2n+1)\pi /2$.

You can also construct many examples of the following type: Let $f(x)=\frac 1  n$  on $[2n,2n+1]$ for $n$ even and $\frac 2  n$ on $[2n,2n+2]$ for $n$  odd. You an easily extend this to piece-weise continuous function satisfying your hypothesis. This function does not decrease after any stage.

Comment: Does not converge to 0 ...

Comment: If you divide by $1+x^2$ instead then it is defined on the whole real line.

Comment: @Gary Fine, but I would consider that insignificant since OP is only interested in what happens near $\infty$.